# How do I pass the name value of a input field into my url?

Tags: php, html

What I'm trying to do is pass whatever is typed into the input field and open a url + whatever was entered into the field.

```
<form method="post" action="http://www.kickass.to/usearch/">

    <div>

        <input type="text" placeholder="Search for a torrent..." name="q">

        <button type="submit">Search</button>

    </div>

</form>
```

This works but the url opens as `http://www.kickass.to/usearch/?=WhateverWasEnteredintoField`

My goal is to get it to open as `http://www.kickass.to/usearch/WhateverWasEnteredintoField`.

I know PHP but I'm pretty sure there's a way to do this in HTML

Comment: Do you have an index.php file in the `usearch` directory? Kinda feels like you have that considering your HTML and your result URL. If so, you can make a few modifications in it.

Comment: This is not done in PHP or HTML, but in the server settings. All server technologies are different, so unless you specify what server software you're using (Apache, NGINX, IIS), we can't give a definitive answer. If you want to find the answer for yourself, Google "{Server software name} Rewrite".

Comment: There is AFAIK not an HTML-only way to do it, but one solution would be to use javascript - and no PHP.

Comment: @MisterMelancholy Couldn't a simple php `header("Location: ...");` do it?

Comment: The header function would redirect the page, but when the page "www.kickass.to/usearch/WhateverWasEnteredintoField" is loaded by the server, it will look for "index.ext" in a directory called "WhateverWasEnteredintoField" and return a 404 if it doesn't exist. This is where the rewrite comes in; the rewrite tells the server not to look for that file, but to do something else.

Comment: He might be using a framework, which automagically translates all additional directories in url to controller parameters, like CodeIgniter for example.

Comment: @MisterMelancholy You're indeed right. I completely forgot that something actually had to handle the new URL as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think .htaccess mod rewrite what your looking for. [(information here)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.htm)

Comment: That number has dropped significantly. According to the [first site in a Google search](http://w3techs.com/technologies/overview/web_server/all), Apache is at 65%. Also, just because it's likely that someone is using something doesn't mean you shouldn't ask first.

Answer (score 0):

Read about "**Generating Rich Text URL**".
and yes, you can accomplish this using mod_rewrite by writing an .htaccess file. A [link](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/the-ultimate-guide-to-htaccess-files/) to help.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to this form action + name using javascript when submit is pressed, like this:

```
<form method="post" action="http://www.kickass.to/usearch/">
<div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search for a torrent..." name="q">
    <button type="submit" onclick="window.location.href = this.form.action + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementsByName('q')[0].value); return false; ">Search</button>
</div>
```

There is no need to do anything on serverside.